# How to check if a given expression is an "explicit algebraic number"?

Tags: functions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry, expression-test

The documentation for [`PossibleZeroQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) says:

> - With the setting [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Method.html)`->"ExactAlgebraics"`, [`PossibleZeroQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PossibleZeroQ.html) will use exact guaranteed methods in the case of explicit algebraic numbers.

Unfortunately, there is no formal definition of what expressions are considered *explicit algebraic numbers*. I noticed that trig functions of rational multiples of `π` are not considered explicit algebraic numbers. Neither are `RootSum` expressions with algebraic functions as a second argument, nor `Re`, `Im` parts of `Root` expressions.

```
In[1]:= PossibleZeroQ[
 Root[-7 + 56 #1^2 - 112 #1^4 + 64 #1^6 &, 4] - Sin[π/7], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]

PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity Root[-7 + 56 #1^2 - 112 #1^4 + 64 #1^6 &, 4,] - Sin[π/7] is equal to zero. Assumіng‌ it is. >>

Out[1]= True

In[2]:= PossibleZeroQ[
 Root[25 + 3300 #1^4 - 530 #1^8 + 20 #1^12 + #1^16 &, 16] - 
  RootSum[5 - 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, Sqrt], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]

PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity Root[25 + 3300 #1^4 - 530 #1^8 + 20 #1^12 + #1^16 &, 16] - RootSum[5 - 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, Sqrt[#1] &] is equal to zero. Assumіng it is. >>

Out[2]= True

In[3]:= PossibleZeroQ[Re[Root[5 + 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]

PossibleZeroQ::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity Re[Root[5 + 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]] is equal to zero. Assumіng it is. >>

Out[3]= True
```

Could you suggest a function that can determine if a given expression is considered an explicit algebraic number from `PossibleZeroQ`'s point of view?

Comment: ...why again are you avoiding `RootReduce[]`?

Comment: Thanks, I am well aware of `RootReduce`. But, first, it can take much time for larger expressions, and if I only need to check for zero, I want to invoke `RootReduce` only if necessary. Second, it does not work for cases like `RootReduce[RootSum[5 - 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, Sqrt]]` so other approaches (e.g. invoke `Normal` first) may be needed.

Comment: Good question. I find it surprising that there is apparently no problem with a `RootSum`, and even more so that the *sum* of a `RootSum` and a `Root` is accepted, but the *difference* isn't. (Differences between `Root`s, though, are handled without any message.)

Comment: Also I found, although your example threw warnings at first time, if I evaluate them again, they'll be quiet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is not an answer, but some clue <strike>which I think might suggest a bug</strike> on what is going on.*

First I'd like to state that the following test is done in *Mathematica* 9.0.1 only, and I have no idea about the cases in other versions.

## The inconsistency

Now let's start a fresh kernel, evaluate one of the examples in the question:

```
PossibleZeroQ[Re[Root[5 + 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]
```

[image]

It threw a warning message as OP described.

Now let's evaluate it *again*:

[image]

To my surprise, the warning is gone!

## Trace it!

To invesgate it more detailed, here is the comparison of `Trace` results:

Restart the kernel, and evaluate the following `Dynamic` command:

```
evalCache = {};
Dynamic[evalCache // StringJoin,
        UpdateInterval -> 0, Initialization :> (evalCache := {})]
```

Keep the `Dynamic` cell visible and evaluate the following trace command:

```
With[{cachelength = 20},
 TraceScan[
  Module[{stopCond = False},
    If[Length[evalCache] > cachelength,
       evalCache = evalCache[[-cachelength ;;]]];
    stopCond = ! FreeQ[#, Message] &&
               ! FreeQ[#, MessageName[PossibleZeroQ, "ztest1"]];
    AppendTo[evalCache,
             StringJoin[Flatten@{ConstantArray["|\t", TraceLevel[] - 2],
                           ToString[
                               Framed[#, FrameStyle -> If[stopCond, Red, Hue[.3, .3, .8]]],
                            StandardForm],
                                 "\n"}]
            ];
    If[stopCond, Print[#]; Abort[]]
    ] &,

  PossibleZeroQ[Re[Root[5 + 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"],

  TraceInternal -> True, TraceDepth -> 2]
 ]
```

Record the result in the `Dynamic` cell, and evaluate `evalCache = {}` to re-initialize the evaluation chain cache, then re-trace. Hopefully you'll see what happened in my Mathematica, that the second trace result is different from the first, fresh one.

This is what the results look like here. (Please open image in new tab/window to see the details.) The **middle** one is the result from the first, fresh trace, the **right** side is from the second trace. For comparison, I also pinned on the **left** side the result for default setting, *i.e.* `PossibleZeroQ[Re[Root[5 + 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]]]`.

Please note the `Method` option they chose. For the fresh one, even though we explicitly specified `Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"`, it seems Mathematica ignored it and went on with the default settings.

[image]

<strike>**My conjecture:** I guess there is a bug here in the method-choosing code.</strike>

[According to J. M.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9771730#9771730), `PossibleZeroQ[]` caches. But nevertheless, hope my trace function will help you/someone find the real answers.

Comment: The caching is easily confirmed: `ClearSystemCache[]; PossibleZeroQ[Re[Root[5 + 20 #1^2 + 16 #1^4 &, 1]], Method -> "ExactAlgebraics"]` will produce an error even if executed repeatedly.

Comment: @J. M. Thanks I see it now. So what do you think about OP's question?

Comment: I haven't the foggiest notion on how to solve it. This will probably need somebody from within WRI to answer.

Comment: @J. M. Agree...