# Check if number is irrational/transcendental

Tags: functions, expression-test

*Mathematica* provides [functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypesOfNumbers.html) to test whether a number is an integer, even or odd, prime, rational, real or complex. However, I could not find any explicit way to determine whether a number is *irrational*, or more precisely *transcendental*.

For instance, Alpha provides a means of determining such properties by simply asking:

```
is pi transcendental?
```

which will return "true" or "false". However, I could not find any matching function in *Mathematica*. Any suggestions?

Comment: So do you want this function to return unevaluated for `EulerGamma`, as an example?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, or something along the lines of "unknown"

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26521)

Comment: _Irrational_ is not the same as _transcendental_: $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, but it's not transcendental.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
istranscendental[x_] := ! Element[x, Algebraics]
```

To the extent that *Mathematica* is aware of the algebraic numbers, this should work. `EulerGamma`, for example, is returned unevaluated, while `Pi` returns `True` and `2` returns `False`.

Comment: This works for simple cases, but is not completely foolproof. [As an example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98467), the expression `HypergeometricPFQ[{1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5}, {1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, 3125/256]` is a root of the polynomial $$x^5-x+1$$ but feeding this expression into this test will yield an unevaluated result.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you - do you have a better solution? If so, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @Pickle, I do not; that is why I was giving it as a cautionary tale.

Comment: Then it looks like the free Alpha has a feature that its expensive brother does not have?

Comment: @Pickle http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%2F5,+2%2F5,+3%2F5,+4%2F5%7D,+%7B1%2F2,+3%2F4,+5%2F4%7D,+3125%2F256%5D+transcendental Wolfram|Alpha doesn't know that one either.

Answer (score 9):

We can use `RootApproximant` and `PossibleZeroQ` to guess if a number is algebraic or not.

```
PossibleAlgebraic[x_] := 
  With[{res = Element[x, Algebraics]},
    res /; BooleanQ[res]
  ]

PossibleAlgebraic[x_?NumericQ] /; !InexactNumberQ[x] := 
  With[{guess = RootApproximant[x]},
    Quiet[PossibleZeroQ[x - guess]] /; Element[guess, Algebraics]
  ]

PossibleAlgebraic[_?NumericQ] = False;
```

Some tests:

```
PossibleAlgebraic[Sqrt[2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
PossibleAlgebraic[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5}, {1/2, 3/4, 5/4}, 3125/256]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
PossibleAlgebraic[π]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
PossibleAlgebraic[EulerGamma]
```

> ```
> False
> ```